# Rewrite lines on file

Tags: c

I need to rewrite a char on a file, or delete some lines. Is there a way to achieve this without rewriting the whole file?

Example: I need to change the char "8" at line 10 with char "4".

```
pollo
ciao fred
98/98/34 42ddw
4
10
1234567890
cristo
ciao liby
98/98/34 fre42ddw
8
20
12345678901234567890
```

Comment: No - if you need to add or remove characters in the middle of the file this isn't possible without re-writing the file - see [Delete a Line from a file in C Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151713/delete-a-line-from-a-file-in-c-language) and many others.  If you're just replacing a character in-place, this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Look at

```
int fseek (stream, offset, origin);
```

You can move to a specific offset and write a symbol there. But to find an offset of char to replace you still need to read all symbols before it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fseek`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fseek.html) and [`fputc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fputc.html), if you know exactly the position of the char. If not, you should better first [`fread`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fread.html) the file and find the needed position. For other utility functions, see [`<stdio.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/stdio.h.html).

Note that `<stdio.h>` is byte-based, rather than line-based. With line-based methods you would basically need to rewrite the file.

For deleting line from the file, well, you *can* just transfer all the characters from the positions `i + [end of the line to be deleted] + 1` to positions `i + [start of the line to be deleted]`. Or read the whole into a buffer and manipulate the characters there. But for such a task, line-based functions are more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, yes, you can modify data at arbitrary positions in the file using [random-access API methods](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/random_access_io.html).  Of course, how the OS and filesystem handle this behind the scenes may result in the entire file being rewritten anyways.