# Comparing a string in a text file in a line and remove that line when found

Tags: c, linux

I have a program which detects new connected ip and logs them in a text file.. e.g

Myconnectedip.txt

```
New Connection from IP: 192.168.5.20
New Connection from IP: 192.168.5.30
```

Now My  program detects that ip 192.168.5.30 has been disconnected. it will update the textfile and remove the line and update my textfile.

```
New Connection from IP: 192.168.5.30
```

Now when i open my textfile the only line i will see is

```
New Connection from IP: 192.168.5.20
```

How can i remove a line string in a textfile?

Here's how i do it..

```
char buff[20];
File *fp
fp = fopen("/tmp/Myconnectedip.txt", w+);

while ( fgets( buff, sizeof(buff), fp ) != NULL ) {
        if ( strstr( buff, "Connection Closed from IP: 192.168.5.20" ) != NULL ) {

            //When found how can i remove that line and update my textfile?.

        } else {
            // nothing to do here..
}
}
close(fp);
```

Thank you..

Comment: You should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151713/delete-a-line-from-a-file-in-c-language

Comment: Why would you delete a line, why don't you simply update the event by adding a new line -> this will be faster easier and more practical, you may also archive older files and control the size of any of the files-> you also receive the advantage of a deeper understanding of the behavior of your system (e.g. additional info such when the connection has been closed, etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy each line one by one  into `buff` as you did and then match with the line which you want to delete from existing file. if not matched then copy it to some temporary file . Do it till eof().
You just don't have to copy the line which you want to delete from the existing file.

After it just rename the temporary file with same name as it was earlier.