# How to delete the first line (not overwritten) of a file in C?

Tags: c, logging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete a Line from a file in C Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151713/delete-a-line-from-a-file-in-c-language)

I know we could overwrite the first line, but here i need to total remove it.

For example, the file contains 100 lines, after i remove the first line, there are 99 lines left and the file size if reduced.

Note that the file is pretty large.

I don't know how to start this, is there any suggestion ? many thanks !

Comment: You would have to write the remaining lines to a temporary file and then move that to the original file.

Comment: @GWW thanks, it is duplicate, i didn't find that Link before.

Comment: @MrROY Since you tagged this question with [logging] - if you are indeed implementing a logger and have a fixed line size, you could implement a circular log and keep a pointer to the current last line.

Comment: `system("tail -n +2 file > file.tmp ; mv file.tmp file");`

Answer (score 0):

collect all the text of your file into a buffer and copy the same back into yoour file and whenever the required line appears, skip it.. This is all you can do..

Comment: If the file is large as the OP indicates, then this may result in out of memory errors. There are far better alternatives available.